# ggmap + geom_point: create variable amount of "geom_points" depending on input. Plotting map

Tags: r, geometry, mapping, coordinates, ggmap

I am plotting maps. I have a dataset with many (lat,lng) coordinates, each one assigned to a type. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(type=c("a", "a", "b", "c"), lat=c(47, 46, 48, 48.5), lng=c(8, 8.9, 8.3, 8.3))

>df
type lat  lng
a    47   8
a    46   8.9
b    48   8.3
c    48.5 8.3
```

What I would love to do is plot the points on a regional map giving each group a different colour. The number of groups-"type" can change depending on input data and is generally large.

So "a" points would be green for example, "b" red and "c" blue.

The method I have used so far to plot small groups is "ggmap":

```
x <- get_stamenmap(...)
ggmap(x) + geom_point(#for a) + + geom_point(#for b)+ geom_point(#for c)
```

And this is of course not feasible if you have +1000 types.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or at least easier?
Maybe another package, or using "for-loops"?

I appreciate any suggestion or comment,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may be helpful. In `geom_point` aesthetic, you can specify that the `color` should be set based on `type` in your data.frame. You would only need to include the `geom_point` statement once. Additionally, if you want to specify the individual colors for different types, you can use `scale_color_manual` and define them there.

```
library(ggmap)

set.seed(12345)

points <- data.frame(type = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T),
                     lon = rnorm(10, -95.4, 0.1),
                     lat = rnorm(10, 29.7, 0.1))

ggmap(get_stamenmap()) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(lon, lat, color = type)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "blue", "B" = "green", "C" = "red", "D" = "orange"))
```

**Map**

[image: map with colored points]